# how to get value from javascript method and assign to header field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have javascript function i need to show data in page(body).i need to show value in chart as well as in the header text. how to show PHvalue in the body part in separate div. shared my code in fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/sahxyx0n/

```
@section scripts{
    <script>
        FusionCharts.ready(function () {
            LoadChart();
        });
        function LoadChart() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("get", "pond")',//remote api address

                type: 'GET',
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        var PHValue = data.sensorsdata.PH;


                        var phfusioncharts = new FusionCharts({
                            type: 'angulargauge',
                            renderAt: 'ph-container',
                            width: '450',
                            height: '300',
                            dataFormat: 'json',
                            dataSource: {
                                "chart": {
                                    "caption": "PH Value ",
                                    "lowerLimit": "0",
                                    "upperLimit": "14",
                                    "showValue": "1",
                                    "valueBelowPivot": "1",
                                    "theme": "fint"
                                },
                                "colorRange": {
                                    "color": [{
                                        "minValue": "0",
                                        "maxValue": "5",
                                        "code": "#e44a00"
                                    }, {
                                        "minValue": "5",
                                        "maxValue": "10",
                                        "code": "#f8bd19"
                                    }, {
                                        "minValue": "10",
                                        "maxValue": "14",
                                        "code": "#6baa01"
                                    }]
                                },
                                "dials": {
                                    "dial": [{
                                        "value": PHValue
                                    }]
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
}
```

Comment: The fiddle is no good to us if you have dependencies such as the `@Url.Action("get", "pond")` part where we don't know the url. Better would be an example that don't involves doing an ajax request and instead give us a fiddle with a sample response

Comment: im getting PH Value is 2.36.that i need to show in div header. var PHValue = data.sensorsdata.PH;

Comment: `$("div").text(PHValue)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function

```
 ....... 
     if (data.success) {
       var PHValue = data.sensorsdata.PH;
       $('#phValue').text(PHValue);
       .....
       .....
```

in your html page add this, where you want to display PHValue,

```
<div id="phValue"></div>
```

Comment: working for div not for h3 , for header not working???
 <h3>PH Value is </h3>: <h3 id="phValue"></h3>
object HTMLHeadingElement//output

Comment: for h3 tag use `$('#phValue').html("Public offers");`

Answer (score 0):

Is this all you want?

```js
function doInit(){
 //alert("Inside doInit() method");
 let time = new Date();
 let timePlaceHolder = document.getElementById("timePlaceHolder");
 timePlaceHolder.innerHTML = "Current Time is: "+time;
}

window.addEventListener("load",doInit,false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Display JS Time</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="only_one_time.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="timePlaceHolder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```